# How to show form after it was closed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, garbage-collection, dispose

I have a MDI application with couple of windows. Is there any way to disable disposing form after it was closed by the user. I want to be able to reopen that form just by calling `form.Show()` method.

Comment: Have you considered hiding the form instead? Just call `form.Hide()` instead of `form.Close()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [Form.FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) Event.

The FormClosing event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the form.

> If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the FormClosingEventArgs passed to your event handler to true.

This should do the same thing as you'd do with Form.Show()

Comment: If you then call Form.Hide() inside that event, you should be all set.

Comment: In that case the form will not be closed. But I want it to be closed and than if user want, to open it again.

Comment: @Peter: Then why do you want to keep it from being disposed? When the form is closed, it is also disposed. If it's hidden, it can be reshown again. If it's closed, you need to recreate it.

Comment: @Lars Thanks, Generally, it works. But from the Window menu of the main form, the "closed" form is removed. How can I avoid it?

Comment: @Peter: Why do you want the form to appear in the Window menu if you've "closed" it? If you want it to appear in the Window menu, then don't close or hide it. I really don't think I understand what your ultimate aim is. Do you know that you can programmatically minimize a form by setting its [`WindowState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx)?

Comment: After canceling in the closing event and performing Hide() the form has disappeared from the Window menu, which is OK. But after I call the Show() method, it is not added to the Window's list. Minimizing form may be a workaround, but it would more natural to hide the form when user press the cross.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values of the Form into a separate class before you call the Close() method of the form and load a new form which takes it's values from the saved class.

Comment: Why to do so? If need to keep form alive lets keep it but in hidden mode, it's no need to create batch of useless code

Comment: why is this pointsless? let's say you hide 100 forms. look how your application goes down to it's knees... but if you save them in a class, maybe create a list of that class and reload them later you don't have 100 hidden forms running there... and that's not unusual! i have programms here which run for 3 or more days now. so please try to think about what could made me post my answer before you critisize it!

Comment: You have a serious problem if your application is creating 100 forms, hidden or not. That *is* unusual, or at least I *hope* it is unusual for you!

Comment: **100 forms ! ! !** is like 100 arrows ready to surface and pierce the app

Comment: he wants to save closed forms not run them simultanios... and my answer was about SAVING and not keep them running...!

Answer (score 0):

send the main form as a parameter to the child form, then the child form can reference the main form t any time

```
    public Form MainForm = null;

    public Sample(ref Form mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private void Sample_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm.Show();
    }
```